# What are some basic rules of thumb to achieve better performance in Perl scripts?

Tags: perl, performance, optimization

I was wondering if you had any basic tips to improve the performance of a Perl script performance (like memoizing determinist functions)?

Comment: Before optimizing anything you should figure out the actual bottlenecks for the script in question.

Comment: Well, actually, there is no script in question, that's more a general question.

Comment: Hello, hello, don't you guys read the blog? You can no longer mark questions as CW!

Comment: Hum... Errr... I don't read the blog... What does CW stands for ?

Comment: @OMG_peanuts I believe CW stands for Community Wiki.  Many people were misusing CWs as a way to avoid downvotes or as punishment for asking broad questions when its original purpose was to lower the reputation bar for editing.

Comment: This is also a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177122/how-can-i-speed-up-my-perl-program and a few questions on general Perl best practices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Install [`Devel::NYTProf`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-NYTProf/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm)
2. run your script with it: `perl -d:NYTProf some_perl.pl`
3. convert the output file into a nice report: `nytprofhtml -f nytprof`
4. open the report in a web browser: `firefox nytprof/index.html`
5. look for whatever is taking the most time
6. determine if that is the right algorithm for the job (e.g. are you using an `O(n`<sup>`2`</sup>`)` algorithm where a `O(n)` algorithm would also work?)
7. extract the slow code to a separate script that can be run by itself
8. write a second (or more) version of the slow code
9. use [`Benchmark`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) to compare them (remember to use data that you expect to see in the wild, some algorithms do great for small numbers of items, but are terrible when the number of items increase)
10. when you have proven that you have faster code, modify the original and go back to step 2 until your code is fast enough or you can't improve it any more
11. if it is still too slow, ask how to do X faster here (be as detailed about X as you can be)

Comment: I love that now that we have Unicode we don’t have to write `O(n**2)` or `O(n^2)`, but can use `O(n²)`, `O(2ⁿ)`, `O(n·log n)`, etc.

Comment: @tchrist I worry about people not having the right font support.  Luckily it looks like `O(n<sup>2</sup>)` works (look at the source for how I made the backticks work, I can't get the comment box to behave properly).

Comment: Yes, SO’s backtick inferencing is sometimes subclever.  The thing with using `<sup>` is that it can throw up line spacing. That’s why `MᶜDonald’s` may look better than using the `<sup>c</sup>` notation.  Alas, `uniprops -a 1d9c` reveals that U+1D9C (MODIFIER LETTER SMALL C) has the `Age:4.1` property, so font support may lag.

Answer (score 7):

You should profile first. Rules are made to be broken.

Some very basic tips:

- Avoid slurping. There are occasions where slurping more than a line is justified, but slurping whole files everywhere is going to exact a price.
- Avoid passing large lists to subroutines.
- If you have multi-level hashes or arrays, avoid repeatedly dereferencing multiple levels. Store a reference to the deepest applicable level in a lexical variable and use that.
- Declare your variables in the smallest scope possible. I am not sure if this is an optimization in and of itself, but frequently will allow you to see more clearly, and that is key to improving performance.

Comment: your first bullet has two parses in English. Did you mean "As much as possible, avoid slurping?" or "Avoid slurping input streams of unlimited size in one fell swoop?"

Comment: @tchrist I meant it in the first sense which helps avoid the latter as well. However, if you do try to slurp streams of unlimited size, the problem will be to get the program to complete, rather than improving performance.

Answer (score 6):

The basic tips for improving the performance of Perl scripts consists of general approaches that apply everywhere, and some very Perl-specific things.

Things like:

- measure, don't guess, and target expensive areas only. Your ROI will be much higher.
- cache unchanging expensive results if you're going to use them a bit.
- don't do something manually when there's a function that will do it for you. This is the difference between interpreted and compiled speed.
- use CPAN, there's a module for *everything*, usually written by people who know Perl better than us mere mortals.

This is not something that's easy to distil into a short pithy answer.

I will give *one* piece of advice. The best way to improve the performance of your code is to post specific bits of it here on SO and wait for the likes of [brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8817/brian-d-foy) to find it :-)

Comment: I totally agree, SO-ers (and specifically brian d foy) are a wonderfull perl optimizer ! ;) But i'm currently interested in the "very Perl-specific things".

Comment: To a first approximation, the speed of a Perl program is inversely proportional to the number of compiled op-codes executed. Therefore built-ins will be faster than writing it yourself.

Comment: So a function that always gives the same answer to the same input can be optimized by the perl compiler?? cool ..

Comment: @Øyvind Skaar No, `perl` will only do that for functions with a 0-ary prototype and a literal return value (e.g. `sub foo() { 5 }`); however you can [`memoize`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Memoize/Memoize.pm) functions with just a simple step.

Answer (score 4):

I recently found out that profiling is very useful, and that [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::NYTProf) is very good at it.. Profiling stops you from unnecessary optimizing and helps you fix the biggest bottlenecks first.

Of course, having some knowledge of what *not* to do helps, but guess that's not very perl specific..

A list of common perl performance gotchas would be nice though :)

**Update:**

here is one: glob() sorts if you don't tell it otherwise :|

don't copy large amounts of data around, use references (e.g.: [Use scalar references to pass large data without copying.](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/298) )

**Duplicate of:** [How can I speed up my Perl program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177122/how-can-i-speed-up-my-perl-program)

Comment: `glob` only *usually* sorts, not always: ` perl -le 'print for <{old,new}.{borrowed,blue}>'`

Answer (score 4):

Many good suggestions here already, here are a few more:

- Avoid repeatedly packing and unpacking arrays, especially when they are large
- `pack` and `unpack` are very fast, but `split` is sometimes faster
- Inline small portions of code rather than breaking everything into subroutines (you can easily go too far with this, so profile to find the hot spots).
- If you want an array of aliases, know your data is mutable, or promise not to change the values, using `sub{\@_}->(retuns_a_list())` is around 40% faster than `[returns_a_list()]` (you don't have to inline the subroutine, I usually call it `sub cap {\@_}` (short for capture)

And if you really, really need to improve the speed of method calls on certain objects, you can use closure based objects.  Here is an excerpt from my module [List::Gen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aGen) discussing the `curse` method of creating closure objects:

- curse HASHREF PACKAGE

  many of the functions in this package utilize closure objects to avoid the speed penalty of dereferencing fields in their object during each access. curse is similar to bless for these objects and while a blessing makes a reference into a member of an existing package, a curse conjures a new package to do the reference's bidding

  ```
  package Closure::Object;
      sub new {
          my ($class, $name, $value) = @_;
          curse {
              get  => sub {$value},
              set  => sub {$value = $_[1]},
              name => sub {$name},
          } => $class
      }
  ```

  Closure::Object is functionally equivalent to the following normal perl object, but with faster method calls since there are no hash lookups or other dereferences (around 40-50% faster for short getter/setter type methods)

  ```
  package Normal::Object;
      sub new {
          my ($class, $name, $value) = @_;
          bless {
              name  => $name,
              value => $value,
          } => $class
      }
      sub get  {$_[0]{value}}
      sub set  {$_[0]{value} = $_[1]}
      sub name {$_[0]{name}}
  ```

  the trade off is in creation time / memory, since any good curse requires drawing at least a few pentagrams in the blood of an innocent package.  the returned object is blessed into the conjured package, which inherits from the provided PACKAGE.

  when fast just isn't fast enough, since most cursed methods don't need to be passed their object, the fastest way to call the method is:

  ```
  my $obj = Closure::Object->new('tim', 3);
  my $set = $obj->{set};                  # fetch the closure
       # or $obj->can('set')


  $set->(undef, $_) for 1 .. 1_000_000;   # call without first arg
  ```

  which is around 70% faster than pre-caching a method from a normal object for short getter/setter methods.

Comment: w00t, thank you. Closure have now taken control over my current project :)

Answer (score 3):

This question reminds me of the [advice of Tim Bunce](http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/27/State-of-the-art%20Profiling%20with%20Devel__NYTProf%20Presentation.pdf), maintainer of [`Devel::NYTProf`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aNYTProf).

To summarize, don't do it unless you really have to.

My favorite quote from his presentation:

> “The First Rule of Program
>   Optimization: Don't do it.
>
> The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it *yet*.”
>
> -[Michael A. Jackson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_A._Jackson)
>
> *[emphasis added]*

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few specific things that haven't been mentioned yet:

- use `tr///` instead of `s///` wherever possible
- use `index()` to match exact substrings instead of a regex
- never ever use `$^`, `$&` and `$-`.  These are the dreaded regex match variables that slow all regexes.  There are alternatives that do not impose a penalty.
- Revenge of the match vars, when using the `English` module, exclude match variable aliasing.  That is, do `use English '-no_match_vars';` instead of just `use English;`

More info can be found in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) and [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: Thank you, I would never think of using tr/// instead of s///...

Comment: You can also do like I do: import from `English` only what you want to use. You'll never get the deprecated match vars with: `use English qw<$EVAL_ERROR $OS_ERROR $PROGRAM_NAME>`.

Comment: do you think it would be possible for English to implement the dreaded three as lazy scalars that only alias themselves to the match vars upon access?  that should allow the simpler use without the performance penalty

Comment: @Eric, interesting idea.  Not sure how to implement.  Maybe with tied variables that, on first access, make the alias and break the tie?  It sucks that a simple `use English` hoses regex performance.

Comment: @daotoad => that's what I'm thinking, playing around with it now, assuming I can get it to work, does this want to be a new module or a patch against English?

Comment: @Eric, making a core module suck less seems like a really good thing. So, I lean pretty heavily towards the patch approach.  The only reason I can see not to do that would be if you have to invoke any particularly scary, rickety magic to make things work.  The `tie` concept seems reasonable for core.  But I haven't started hanging out in p5p yet.

Comment: @Eric Strom, I was talking about this with someone who pointed out that with a tie, the first invocation of the English versions of the match variables would fail, because no data would be collected for them when the regex runs.