# Efficient use of Perl hash

Tags: performance, perl, hash

I'm using a hash to abbreviate state names

```
%STATEABBRIVATE = ('ALABAMA' => 'AL',
                   ...);
```

Some of my input sets already have abbreviated state names. Would it be more efficient to use an `if defined $STATEABBRIVATE{$state}` or to add another 51 matched pairs `'AL'=>'AL'` to the hash?

Comment: If you want to verify that the state really exists, using `AL => 'AL'` might be the easiest way.

Comment: `$state = $STATEABBRIVATE{$state} if length($state) > 2`

Comment: If the question is about performance, the answer is: it doesn't matter. (Any difference would be negligible/unnoticeable.)

Comment: On a large enough data set I'm not sure that's true.

Comment: Sure, you can scrape a few cycles by not mapping based on some conditioin (e.g. string length == 2). But doing the mapping for all values allows validation. Since the hash length is finite (100 values), lookup will be very efficient. Not validating input to avoid looking up a hash key seems premature optimization to me.

Comment: @OBoud Isn't your data set 50-100 items?

Comment: @kba - This was the discussion I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @Matt Jacob - The particular set I'm currently working on is 20k lines. The practical bound is probably under a couple hundred k but this was more of a philosophical question. ;)
Though I'm running this on a raspberry pi rev 1 so...

Comment: Ohhh... you're talking about the amount of input data and not the size of the hash. OK, got it. The answer is still the same: it doesn't matter.

Comment: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil". Don't optimise speculatively.  Write code that's clear what it's doing. If there's a need to optimise, then run a profiler. Chances are, there won't be - computers are pretty fast these days, so for most data sets, you won't save a significant amount of time. (if at all, once you've optimised it, then realised in 6 months time you don't understand it any more)

Comment: Rule 1 of Optimization Club: Do not optimize.  Rule 2 of Optimization Club: Do not optimize without measuring first.

Comment: @AndyLester Wouldn't 1 and 2 both be that you don't talk about Optimization Club?

Comment: As they nicely said, do not optimize first.  Now ... adding the extra pairs to the hash somewhere at top of code is a one-time operation and the later look-up of a hash is constant anyway.  This _has to_  beat running `define` or `exist` every single time.  If this is done often, of course.  So I'd say that enlarging the hash is more efficient hands down.  However, firstly it won't matter.

Comment: Here's the full rules of Optimization Club: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177122/how-can-i-speed-up-my-perl-program/177132

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify that the state really exists, using `AL => 'AL'` might be the easiest way.

To keep your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), you can just

```
my %STATEABBRIVATE = ( ALABAMA => 'AL',
                       ...
                     );
my @abbrevs = values %STATEABBRIVATE;
@STATEABBRIVATE{@abbrevs} = @abbrevs;
```

If you're concenrned about performance, the bottleneck is probably somewhere else:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Benchmark qw{ cmpthese };
use Test::More;

my %hash = qw( Alabama AL Alaska AK Arizona AZ Arkansas AR California CA
               Colorado CO Connecticut CT Delaware DE Florida FL
               Georgia GA Hawaii HI Idaho ID Illinois IL Indiana IN
               Iowa IA Kansas KS Kentucky KY Louisiana LA Maine ME
               Maryland MD Massachusetts MA Michigan MI Minnesota MN
               Mississippi MS Missouri MO Montana MT Nebraska NE
               Nevada NV Ohio OH Oklahoma OK Oregon OR Pennsylvania PA
               Tennessee TN Texas TX Utah UT Vermont VT Virginia VA
               Washington WA Wisconsin WI Wyoming WY );

$hash{'West Virginia'}  = 'WV';
$hash{'South Dakota'}   = 'SD';
$hash{'South Carolina'} = 'SC';
$hash{'Rhode Island'}   = 'RI';
$hash{'North Dakota'}   = 'ND';
$hash{'North Carolina'} = 'NC';
$hash{'New York'}       = 'NY';
$hash{'New Mexico'}     = 'NM';
$hash{'New Jersey'}     = 'NJ';
$hash{'New Hampshire'}  = 'NH';

my %larger = %hash;
@larger{ values %hash } = values %hash;

sub def {
    my $state = shift;
    return defined $hash{$state} ? $hash{$state} : $state
}

sub ex {
    my $state = shift;
    return exists $hash{$state} ? $hash{$state} : $state
}

sub hash {
    my $state = shift;
    return $larger{$state}
}

is(def($_), ex($_),   "def-ex-$_")   for keys %larger;
is(def($_), hash($_), "def-hash-$_") for keys %larger;

done_testing();

cmpthese(-1,
         { hash => sub { map hash($_), keys %larger },
           ex   => sub { map ex($_),   keys %larger },
           def  => sub { map def($_),  keys %larger },
         });
```

Results:

```
        Rate  def   ex hash
def  27307/s   --  -2% -11%
ex   27926/s   2%   --  -9%
hash 30632/s  12%  10%   --
```

Comment: The easy implementation is what had me second guessing the efficiency of the solution.

Comment: @MattJacob: Without seeing the code, one can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

Both `if defined $STATEABBRIVATE{$state}` and any hash lookups are going to be constant time (i.e. O(1) operations). In fact, `defined()` probably uses a hash table lookup behind the scenes anyway. So, my prediction is that the difference in performance is going to be negligible, even with large data sets. This is, at best, an educated guess.