# Python self keyword: advantages and drawbacks

Tags: python-3.x

What is the difference between these 2 classes (in terms of performance and design):

```
 class A:
        def methodA(self):
           self.a=10
           print(self.a)
```

And:

```
 class B:
        def methodB(self):
           b=10
           print(b)
```

Comment: They do completely different things. `self` is not optional, like `this` in Java. See e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained). Hint: Move `print(self.a)` and `print(b)` to a second method and see what happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b` in the second example is [local variable](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example), not [class-instance (or static class) variable](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects), so with the first example you can do:

```
o = A()
o.methodA()
print(o.a)
```

With the second example this results into error and variable `b` runs out of scope after `methodB()` finishes.

About performance... By default instance variables are implemented via dictionary:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = 5
...
>>> o = A()
>>> dir(o)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__g
e__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__',
'__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '_
_setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'a']
>>> o.__dict__
{'a': 5}
>>> o.__dict__.__class__
<class 'dict'>
```

So every access is basically like doing `self.__dict__['a']`, performance notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419324/1149736).