# Is it a bad practice to let called methods handle business that the caller class could have handled?

Tags: python, oop

I'm doing some code here and faced this good/bad practice dilemma:

```
        message_id = self.get_message_id(msg)
        Notification.set_notification_type(self, message_id)
```

As you can see, I get some return from `self.get_message_id(msg)` and send it as an argument to `Notification.set_notification_type()`.

My question is: should I, instead of doing this above, do this:

```
        Notification.set_notification_type(self, msg)
```

And then, on the `Notification.py` file:

```
        def set_notification_type(obj, msg):
            message_id = obj.get_message_id(msg)
```

That is, should I receive raw things in the method and use the `obj` parameter to handle what I have to handle or should I send everything already handled by the `obj`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be more readable and would define clearly what your `set_notification_type` method would give and what it expects as parameters.

```
def get_notification_type(messageId):
        //Do stuff to populate notificationType
        return notificationType;

message_id = self.get_message_id(msg)
notification_type = Notification.get_notification_type(message_id)
```

I am from c# background. So the syntax might have mistakes. Try to keep the method definition as clear as possible so that it can be reused easily.

Comment: Great, thank you! I guess this has something to do with "low coupling and high cohesion" right?

Comment: You are welcome. I think we can't relate low coupling and high cohesion to above scenario. Low coupling and high cohesion comes to picture when we talk about classes and modules and their inter-dependability. Here there might be a performance implication according to these two posts. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570175/python-self-keyword-advantages-and-drawbacks   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418588/how-expensive-are-python-dictionaries-to-handle/1419324#1419324