# Will python provide enough performance for a proxy?

Tags: python, performance, proxy

I want to start writing a http proxy that will modify responses according to some rules/filters I will configure. However, before I start coding it, I want to make sure I'm making the right choice in going with Python. Later, this tool would have to be able to process a lot of requests, so, I would like to know I can count on it later on to be able to perform when "push comes to shove".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think you will find Python to be perfectly adequate for your needs.  There's a huge number of web frameworks, WSGI libraries, etc. to choose from, or learn from when building your own.

There's an interesting [post](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/01/microsoft-ships-python-code-in-1996.html) on the [Python History blog](http://python-history.blogspot.com/) about how Python was supporting high performance websites in 1996.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the bulk of the processing uses Python's built-in modules it should be fine as far as performance. The biggest strength of Python is its clear syntax and ease of testing/maintainability. If you find that one section of your code is slowing down the process, you can rewrite that section and use it as a C module, while keeping the bulk of your control code in Python.

However if you're looking to make the most optimized Python Code you may want to check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172720/speeding-up-python).

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on the library you use more than the language itself.  The [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) framework is known to scale well.

Here's a [proxy server example in python/twisted](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Twisted-Examples) to get you started.

Bottomline: choose your third party tools wisely and I'm sure you'll be fine.

Comment: I don't think I will be using any third party libraries. Not in the initial phase, anyway.

Comment: I'd advise against that approach, but to each his own.  Still, the fact that twisted exists and is quite scalable should answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Python performs pretty well for most tasks, but you'll need to change the way you program if you're used to other languages.  See [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) for more info.

If plain old CPython doesn't give the performance you need, you have other options as well.
As has been mentioned, you can extend it in C (using a tool like [swig](http://www.swig.org/) or [Pyrex](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/)).  I also hear good things about [PyPy](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/) as well, but bear in mind that it uses a restricted subset of Python.  Lastly, a lot of people use [psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) to speed up performance.